# SQL Server : search 2 tables using a LIKE opertaor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table `Cases` with a column that contains casenumbers and a column called `match`.

I also have another table `Messages`. In this table there is one column called `Message` that contains large amounts of random text strings that may or may not contain the case number noted in the `Case` table.

What I want to do is loop through every single record in table `Cases` and see if each of those case numbers exist anywhere within a record in the message column in table `Messages`.

I need to use the LIKE operator which includes the case number from `Cases` (casenumbers). If a case number is found anywhere in table `Messages`, I want to update `Cases.Match` column to 1 (true).

I am lost as how to accomplish this. So far I am just trying to get casenumbers that exist somewhere in the `Message` column in table `Messages`.

```
SELECT *
FROM Cases
INNER JOIN Messages ON Cases.CaseNumber LIKE '%'+ Messages.Message + '%'
```

Data structures

**Cases**:

- Casenumber VARCHAR(MAX)
- Match BIT

**Messages**:

- Message VARCHAR(MAX)

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: If there are no matches for a specific `CaseNumber` do you want to (re)set `match` to `0` or just leave it unchanged?

Comment: @HABO leave it unchanged

Comment: Are there any delimiters for the case number? Without them how do you avoid finding that `'4'` is in `'Pi is about 3.1415.'`? Are all case numbers the same length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> see if each of those casenumbers exist anywhere within a record in the message

Your first problem is that you are using `LIKE` the wrong way. This condition:

```
Cases.CaseNumber LIKE '%'+ Messages.Message + '%'
```

should be written the other way around:

```
Messages.Message LIKE '%'+ Cases.CaseNumber + '%'
```

---

> If a case number is found anywhere in table 2(messages) I want to update table1 "match" column to 1 (true).

You could write an `UPDATE` query that uses a correlated subquery to check if the current case has a match in the messages table:

```
UPDATE c
SET c.match = 1
FROM cases c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM messages m
    WHERE m.Message LIKE '%' + c.CaseNumber + '%'
)
```

Comment: I **think** `update cases c` is incorrect syntax.  `UPDATE c set match=1 from cases c WHERE . . .`

Comment: I always like to add `and match <> 1` to the where clause so we're not updating rows that are already 1.  **BUT** I don't actually know if it makes any difference.

Comment: @avery_larry: you are right about the syntax, I just modified the query. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @GMB Thank you this query worked out perfectly.@avery_larry thanks for noticing syntax issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
create stored procedure update_if_found
    (@casenumber varchar(max)) 
as
begin
    if exists(select 1 from messages where message like '%'+ @casenumber +'%')
        update cases 
        set match = 1 
        where casenumber = @casenumber
end;
```

Run this procedure for every row in cases (see fetch for examples)

Comment: I think this is basically RBAR . . ?  If so, then it is a bad idea.

Comment: RBAR is only bad if you don't understand what you are doing :)

Comment: And if someone understood what they were doing they probably wouldn't need to ask a question on SO.. I agree with Avery; this could be done as a set operation- there's no need to RBAR it

Comment: "Set-based" approach above does exactly the same thing, it goes through every row and applies inner select. Look at the plan if you can't see it directly. The difference is, if you need to update millions of rows, update above may fail for the lack of log space, because it's all done in one transaction. In my approach, you can actually batch it into reasonable size.